# How to create custom grid like sales order in magento2?

Tags: magento2, sales-order, order-grid

How to create custom grid like sales order gird with new,edit,save,delete,status,massdelete..etc in magento2.?

Answer (score 0):

Without more information I would recommend to take a look into simple tutorials as [Tutorial Ashsmith](https://www.ashsmith.io/magento2/module-from-scratch-part-5-adminhtml/). It was an enormous help for me.
More information you might find in core modules that already have grids with filters etc implemented or in the official [DevDocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/ui-components/ui-component.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use this link to create simple module having add,edit,delete functionalities and than try to understand structure of it. it helps me a lot to understand magento 2 module structure :
http://cedcommerce.com/magento-2-module-creator/

1. Create module as per need.
2. Put it into app/code/module created by you.
3. Run upgrade command from `cmd : yourprojectfolder >php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Comment: 1 . crete module as per need
2.  put it into app/code/module creted by you
3.  run upgrade command from cmd :
      yourprojectfolder>php bin/magento setup:upgrade